$w = \frac{2z + 3}{z - 4}$ maps the circle $x^2 + y^2 - 4x = 0$ onto the straight line $4u + 3 = 0$
Our question is:
Show that the transformation $w = \frac{2z + 3}{z - 4}$ maps the circle $x^2 + y^2 - 4x = 0$ onto the straight line $4u + 3 = 0$.
So, here's the solution:
We have,
$$
w = \frac{2z + 3}{z - 4}
$$
The inverse transformation is
$$
z = \frac{4w + 3}{w - 2} \tag{1}
$$
Now the circle $x^2 + y^2 - 4x = 0$ can be written as
$$
z\overline{z} - 2(z + \overline{z}) = 0
$$
Substituting for $z$ and $\overline{z}$ from (1), we get
$$
\frac{4w + 3}{w - 2} \cdot \frac{4\overline{w} + 3}{\overline{w} - 2} - 2 \left( \frac{4w + 3}{w - 2} + \frac{4\overline{w} + 3}{\overline{w} - 2} \right) = 0
$$
$$
\implies 16w\overline{w} + 12w + 12\overline{w} + 9 - 2(4w\overline{w} + 3\overline{w} - 8w - 6 + 4w\overline{w} + 3w - 8\overline{w} - 6) = 0
$$
$$
22(w + \overline{w}) + 33 = 0 \implies 22(2u) + 33 = 0 \implies 4u + 3 = 0
$$
Thus, circle is transformed into a straight line.
$$
\left[\begin{array}{l}  
z = x + iy \\  
\overline{z} = x - iy  
\end{array}\right]
$$
$$
\left[\begin{array}{l}  
w = u + iv \\  
\overline{w} = u - iv  
\end{array}\right]
$$

My question is on how do we reach to the following expression

$$
\frac{4w + 3}{w - 2} \cdot \frac{4\overline{w} + 3}{\overline{w} - 2} - 2 \left( \frac{4w + 3}{w - 2} + \frac{4\overline{w} + 3}{\overline{w} - 2} \right) = 0
$$
$$
\implies 16w\overline{w} + 12w + 12\overline{w} + 9 - 2(4w\overline{w} + 3\overline{w} - 8w - 6 + 4w\overline{w} + 3w - 8\overline{w} - 6) = 0
$$

The book I am currently using does not care to introduce a few more in-between steps on how to reach to the next step. I have tried for the straight two hours on trying to deduce it but no success. I really don't understand where I am going wrong. Maybe this complete solution is incorrect but that is very unlikely. If anyone could care to explain the in-between steps, it will be really helpful. Thanks!

Multiply by $(w-2)(\bar w-2)$ and expand?

Start from $$
\frac{4w + 3}{w - 2} \cdot \frac{4\overline{w} + 3}{\overline{w} - 2} - 2 \left( \frac{4w + 3}{w - 2} + \frac{4\overline{w} + 3}{\overline{w} - 2} \right) = 0
$$
Multiplying by $(w-2)(\overline{w} -2)$, we obtain
$$(4w+3)(4\overline{w}+3) - 2[(4w+3)(\overline{w}-2) + (4\overline{w}+3)(w-2)] = 0 $$
Expand $(4w+3)(4\overline{w}+3) = 16w\overline{w} + 12w + 12\overline{w} + 9$, $(4w+3)(\overline{w}-2) =  4w\overline{w} + 3\overline{w} - 8w - 6$ and $(4\overline{w}+3)(w-2) = 4w\overline{w} + 3w - 8\overline{w} - 6$ to obtain
$$
16w\overline{w} + 12w + 12\overline{w} + 9 - 2(4w\overline{w} + 3\overline{w} - 8w - 6 + 4w\overline{w} + 3w - 8\overline{w} - 6) = 0.
$$

Ohh and ohh. I understand where I was going wrong. I first multiplied the later part of the LHS by -2 and didn't keep the sign on outside then begin with the expansion which was obviously wrong. After that every time I went towards some other approach, I started from that second step leading my every answer wrong. I feel really dump right now. I am failing at elementary algebra .
Now I am questioning my life choices but at least I got my answer! Thanks for taking time to look into my stupid question and also sorry. Have a good day/night!
